# How can I copy the content of one column to another one?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have following table structure:

```
// Posts
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| id |  title  |  content_html   | content_markdown |   content_edit_html    | content_edit_markdown  |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | title1  | <b>content1</b> | **content1**     | <b>content1_edited</b> | **content1_edited**    |
| 2  | title2  | <i>content2</i> | *content2*       |                        |                        |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

As you see in the above table, I just keep two last edit (`content(html/markdown)` is one before the last edit or the content without editing and `content_edit(html/markdown)` is last edit or empty if there isn't any edit)

---

Now please take a look at these two examples:

**Example One:** I want to edit first post **which is edited** already. Here is new value:

```
**content1_new_value**
```

Well I also convert it to html using a PHP library and make this:

```
<b>content1_new_value</b>
```

I want to fill (update) the content of `content_(html/markdown)` with the current content of `content_edit_(html/markdown)` and fill (update) this column `content_edit_(html/markdown)` with new value, something like this:

```
+----+---------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
| id |  title  |  content_html          | content_markdown     | content_edit_html          | content_edit_markdown  |
+----+---------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | title1  | <b>content1_edited</b> | **content1_edited**  | <b>content1_new_value</b>  | **content1_new_value** |
+----+---------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
```

---

**Example Two:** I want to edit second post **which is not edited** already. Here is new value:

```
*content2_new_value*
```

Well I also convert it to html using a PHP library and make this:

```
<i>content2_new_value</i>
```

In this case I want to keep `content_(html/markdown)` intact (without any change) and just update `content_edited_(html/markdown)` with new value, something like this:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| id |  title  |  content_html   | content_markdown |   content_edit_html    | content_edit_markdown    |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2  | title2  | <i>content2</i> | *content2*       | *content2_new_value*   | <i>content2_new_value</i>|
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So as you see, I just keep the two last edit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check CASE WHEN ELSE END

```
case  
when content_edit_html is not null
update table set content_html = content_edit_html, content_markdown = content_edit_markdown, 
content_edit_html = <b>content1_new_value</b>, content_edit_markdown = **content_new_value**
where id = 1
else
update table set content_edit_html = <b>content1_new_value</b>, content_edit_markdown = **content_new_value**
where id = 1
end
```

Comment: @stack If the answer solves your problem, you should also mark it as correct.